# Programme(Youtube download videos)

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
from pytube import YouTube
root=Tk()
root.geometry("400x350")
root.title("Youtube video downloader application")
def download():
    try:
        myVar.set("Downloading...")
        root.update()
        Youtube(link.get()).streams.first().download()
        link.set("Video download successfully")
    except Expection as e:
        myVar.set("Mistake")
        root.update()
        link.set("Enter correct link")
        Label(root,text="Welcome to youtube\nDownloader Application",font="Consolas 15 bold").pack()
        myVar=StringVar()
        myVar.set("Enter the link below")
        Entry(root,textvariable=myVar,width=40).pack(pady=10)
        link=StringVar()
        Entry(root, textvariable=myVar, width=40).pack(pady=10)
        Button(root,text="Download video",command=download).pack()
        root.mainloop()
```

It is my code,but this code don't work(Programme finished 0)(Before that I install tkinter,pytube.).I don't know how to rework this code.

Comment: Where do you ever call your `download()` function?

Comment: @takendarkk second last line i believe

Comment: That is setting an event listener. It is not actually calling the function. That code won't even execute until the function is called.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `root.mainloo()` at the global level, outside of the `download` function.